# How to put data of the same type in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to make an array with data for a list of videogames and want it to be able to have multiple genres, how do i do that?

```
{
name: "The Last of Us",
console: 'PS3',
genre: 'Horror',
genre: 'Stealth',
genre: 'Survival',
}
```

it only takes the last genre, is there a way to assign multiple values to genre so that it takes into account all of them?

Comment: Title says array.... so use an array.... `genre: ['.', '..', '...']`

Comment: ```{
name: "The Last of Us",
console: 'PS3',
genre: ['Horror','Stealth','Survival']
}```

Answer (score 3):

You can "nest":

- an array in an array
- an array and an object
- an object in an array

[In your example , you have a json object](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/constructing-a-nested-json-object-in-javascript) ( not an array)

example for json-object :

Simple way:  define an array for the property:

```
const obj = {
    name: "The Last of Us",
    console: 'PS3',
    genre: ['Horror','Stealth','Survival']   
};
```

Or, assign it after creation:

```
var obj = {
    name: "The Last of Us",
    console: 'PS3' 
};
obj.genre = ['Horror','Stealth','Survival'];
```

[An "array-only" would be defined like this](https://selftaughttxg.com/2023/01-23/how-to-write-a-recursive-function-in-javascript-for-beginners/):

```
const yay = [1, 2, [3, [4, [5, [6, [[[[[7], [8, 9]]]]]]], 10]]];
```